# Next Auth is not working with the new Next JS 13

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, next-auth

Please help me. ever since i started using Next 13 app dir, it's been a hell. most of the code that worked on the prev version it's not working with this one. so is Next Auth.

I'm connecting my firebase to Next Auth. so i did as i always do. i created `firebase.js` file and `[...nextauth].js` file inside `/pages/api/auth` path. the code is as follows.

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

export const app =
  getApps().length > 0 ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { db } from "../../../firebase";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  }),
  // ...
});
```

the first problem is when i import `db` from `firebase.js` it shows an error in `FirestoreAdapter()`, i made that work by directly passing the `firebaseConfig` inside the adapter. and it worked, and registered me to firestore nicely.

to connect this to my app, i wrap the entire app with `sessionProvider` in `layout.js`.

layout.js

```
function RootLayout({ children }) {
  // const { store } = wrapper.useWrappedStore();
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <AuthProvider>
          <ChakraProvider>{children}</ChakraProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`AuthProvider` is where i imported `SessionProvider`.

the next problem i faced was when i use the session it crashes the app. sometimes it works fine, and next the app stops working, no functionality works. when i use the session on header to display the name, image and email of the session, it displays. but when i try to use the session if the user is authenticated or not, sometimes it works sometimes the app crashes. in both cases tho if it worked initially then upon refresh it completely crashes. nothing to be displayed and the browser alerts me that the app stops working and i need to exit.

in the header section i first imported `import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";`. then created instance `const { data: session } = useSession();`. and finally

```
       <div className=" w-10 relative -z-10 h-10 rounded-full cursor-pointer ">
          <Image
            src={session?.user?.image}
            alt="profile"
            fill
            className="w-full h-full top-0 left-0 rounded-full -z-10 object-cover"
          />
        </div>
```

this part works. the part where it doesn't work is in page.jsx, for authentication. i did the import part the same as header

```
{!session ? (
        // signIn()
        <div className="px-4 py-2 bg-red-300" onClick={() => signIn()}>
          logIn please
        </div>
      ) : ( <div>hello</div> )}
```

this is the part it got me stuck.

the final part it doesn't work is the `sessionProvider` doesn't make the glitch stop when user refresh the page.

can anyone please help me on how to do it correctly?

Comment: Same, Next 13 not working with next-auth.

Answer (score 2):

I do not use next-auth but have used Nextjs 13 appdir with firebase.

My advice would be to:

1. determine which components need to be client-side and mark them with "use client". This was the main culprit in a lot of bugs I faced in making firebase v9 work with nextjs 13 appDir. You can use the suggested method of using third-party libraries here: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#third-party-packages
2. read the next-auth github issue in relation to appDir https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/5647

If **next-auth is not a requirement**, and you just want to use the nextjs 13 appDir with firebase, then here is a **starter template**: https://github.com/surya-ven/next-firebase-auth-starter. It mainly focuses on authentication, but you can add your own firestore or storage functions as required.

Answer (score 0):

I think there a few issues, but I can't tell for sure seeing not much of your code:

> AuthProvider is where i imported SessionProvider.

In next 13 you can't just put React Server Components inside of client components, you need to wrap them. Also shown here: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#nesting-server-components-inside-client-components
For example:

```
'use client';

import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

export default function NextAuthProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
}
```

Then you can use them, just as before:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import NextAuthProvider from '@/components/auth/NextAuthProvider';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

export default function DashboardLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <NextAuthProvider>
      <section>
        {children}
      </section>
    </NextAuthProvider>
  );
}
```

The other issue:

> the next problem i faced was when i use the session it crashes the app. sometimes it works fine, and next the app stops working, no functionality works. when i use the session on header to display the name, image and email of the session, it displays. but when i try to use the session if the user is authenticated or not, sometimes it works sometimes the app crashes. in both cases tho if it worked initially then upon refresh it completely crashes. nothing to be displayed and the browser alerts me that the app stops working and i need to exit.

You need to make sure, that you are not using useSession inside a React Server Component, just tested it in my project:

```
//working example
'use client';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const Page = () => {
  const { push } = useRouter();
  const { data: session, status } = useSession({
    required: true,
    onUnauthenticated: () => {
      push('/admin/signIn');
      return <h1>login required</h1>;
    },
  });

  const loading = status === 'loading';
  if (loading) return <h1>loading...</h1>;
  if (!session) return <h1>login required</h1>;

  return (
    <div>
       works
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

compared to mistakingly making it async:

```
//breaks
'use client';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const Page = async () => {
  const { push } = useRouter();
  const { data: session, status } = useSession({
    required: true,
    onUnauthenticated: () => {
      push('/admin/signIn');
      return <h1>login required</h1>;
    },
  });

  const loading = status === 'loading';
  if (loading) return <h1>loading...</h1>;
  if (!session) return <h1>login required</h1>;

  return (
    <div>
       breaks
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Hope that resolves your Issue, sorry that I don't have any documentation links, that's just what I've found out by trial and error and a little bit of intuition from working with next 13.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend updating your web application to use [Firebase Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) on the server side instead of relying solely on Next-Auth. This approach will give you better control over session management. Specifically, Firebase Admin allows you to [manage session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies), which can be customized to fit the needs of your web app. Check out the relevant documentation for handling session cookies with Firebase Admin for more information. There are [example codes](https://github.com/victorfu/psyduck-next/blob/master/src/app/api/login/route.ts#L60).